# mysql selecting two DISTINCT value from two different columns from a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to display country and their flag image. I have stored this in two columns named Country and flag in my table "College".

I tried this

```
$sql = "SELECT `Country`, `flag` FROM `College` group by `Country`, `flag` ORDER BY `Country` ASC";
```

Tried this too.

```
$sql_COU = "SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT `Country` FROM `College`) as `Country`, (SELECT DISTINCT `flag` FROM `College`) as `flag`";
```

I also tried

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Country`, `flag` FROM  `College`";
```

But my result is duplicating.

Comment: Can you give sample data?

Comment: Sure @Eggsalad. I try to add this to my ques.

Comment: @Eggsalad. I am sharing you the sample data here. College =MIT, Standford, Imperial College, University Of Waterloo, Queensland University of Technology. | Country = USA, UK, Australia, Australia. | Flag = USA.jpg, UK.jpg, AUS.jpg, AUS.jpg

Comment: Thanks! See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way of doing it would be to create a "countries" table with the names and flags for each.

Then, you would only have to create a country_id field in your college table to relate to the proper country.

This way, you would not have the problem of managing duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Keep in mind you might have many colleges from the same country.  Entering for each of them the name of the country and the flag image path is redundant.

A simple :
Select * FROM countries;

would give you exactly what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Country, ANY_VALUE(flag) FROM College GROUP BY Country
```

For the data given in the comments under the question, this gives:

```
Country   | flag
-------------------
USA       | USA.jpg
UK        | UK.jpg
Australia | AUS.jpg
```

Comment: Not sure why the vote down. This works for data he gave.

Comment: i think this will not display the DISTINCT Value. This will display the duplicate value.

Comment: ? This displays as above.

Comment: There is no problem in sql for which the above could be a solution.

Comment: If I misunderstood the question, please explain. I'm sincerely interested. I realize this is a simple answer, but I thought he wanted to display countries and their flags without duplicating. In the comments under the question, he gives sample data. This answer query gives the results above given that sample data. How is that not the result he wants?

Comment: The question is immaterial. This is not a valid query. A quirk of MySQL is that it allows this query (in older or unmodified versions anyway). It's questionable whether this constitutes a bug or a feature. Either way, the manual discusses it at great length. Oh, and if you fail to '@' address a comment to a commentator, then they won't necessarily see it.

Comment: @Eggsalad Let me test this with my code. Will let you know the results. Hope this will work. Thank you.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the info. After reading [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), I added `ANY_VALUE()` to the `flag` column as it's always determined by `Country`.